# how to remove the divergent term from the summation?

Tags: summation

I am doing the summation over two indices: `m and n`
Suppose I want to remove those terms from the summation which has `m==n`, what is the command for that? Because at `m==n`, terms are divergent.

I have already tried to do the summation in two cases:
`m` less than `n` and `m>n`.
But is there any other method to do it in one step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try also this:

```
    Sum[f[n, m] /. f[__] /; m == n -> 0, {n, 1, 3}, {m, 1, 3}]

(*   f[1, 2] + f[1, 3] + f[2, 1] + f[2, 3] + f[3, 1] + f[3, 2]  *)
```

The advantage is that if `f[n,n]`is divergent, Mma does not complain.

Answer (score 1):

if the expression is not evaluated inside the Sum then you can try:

```
DeleteCases[Sum[f[n, m], {n, 1, 3}, {m, 1, 3}], f[i_, i_]]
(*f[1, 2] + f[1, 3] + f[2, 1] + f[2, 3] + f[3, 1] + f[3, 2]*)
```

if the expression is evaluated then try:

```
ind = DeleteCases[Tuples[Range[3], 2], {i_, i_}];
Total[f[#, #2] & @@@ ind]
(*f[1, 2] + f[1, 3] + f[2, 1] + f[2, 3] + f[3, 1] + f[3, 2]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sum[f[n, m], {n, 3}, {m, n + 1, 3}] +  Sum[f[n, m], {n, 3}, {m, 1, n - 1}]
```

Comment: Thanks. This I have already tried (dividing into two cases).